# convert a class type object to Intptr

Tags: c#, windows, interop

helo
I know this may be easy but believe me I didn't understud it from what I found on google.
I trying to do the folowing thing :

`unsafe static IntPtr __convertSearcherCallbackParameterToIntPtr (SearcherCallbackParameter searcherCallbackParameter )
        {
            return (*(IntPtr*)&searcherCallbackParameter);
        }`

where SearcherCallbackParameter  is a class and I need to convert it to an IntPtr so I can pass it as a parameter to a windows api.

I get the folowing error:
Cannot take the address of, get the size of, or declare a pointer to a managed type

Comment: the CLR reserves the right to move you object around in memory, so even if you could get the address of the managed object, the address would almost certainly be invalidated very quickly. Do you mind stating which API call you are trying to use?

Comment: I'm trying to you EnumWindows , and EnumChildWindows , to which I need to send a pointer ( or IntPtr ) to SearcherCallbackParameter. so my callback can recieve it.

Comment: hare is who I declare the fcts:                              private delegate bool EnumWindowsProc(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lParam);
        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern bool EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc callback, IntPtr extraData);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use a simple .NET delegate, the interop layer will take care of the marshalling. The following code takes the native function declarations from http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/EnumWindows.html

The callback function parameter is just an integer though so it doesn't actually have to be an IntPtr.

```
public delegate bool CallBackPtr(int hwnd, int lParam);


[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool EnumWindows(CallBackPtr lpEnumFunc, UInt32 lParam);


static bool callbackreport(int hwnd, int lparam)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", hwnd, lparam);
    return true;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    EnumWindows(Program.callbackreport,0);
}
```